# can't get text align to right to the footer of div

Tags: css, text-align

```
.footer p:nth-child(2) {
background-color:blue;
text-align: right;
}

<!--Calling of footer class here-->
<div class="footer">
<p>Copyright &copy; 2015 Jon Chretien. All rights reserved.</p>
<p>Feel free to reach out through <a href="www.dummy.com"> email</a>,<a href="www.dummy.com">Twitter</a>, <a href="#">Github</a>, and <a href="#">LinkedIn</a></p>
</div>
```

hello i'm a beginner in web designing and currently i'm trying to copy a web for practice..i have two paragraphs and i want second paragraph to align in the right side of footer i used n-th child for this purpose but it doesn't work...its strange when i apply `background-color: blue;` to that paragraph then it is applied but when i apply`text-align:right;`then it doesn't work on it what is the error kindly help me out thanks

Comment: Working fine https://jsfiddle.net/04adx8sc/

Comment: its working @vampz check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2rf4oa0j/1/

Comment: i'm using the adobe dreamweaver in that it doesn't work now i understand sometimes our code is right and its fault of ide...thanks a lot @Suresh

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `:nth-of-type(2)` which is more useful than `:nth-child`